# Create additional WiFi via dongle while remaining connected to the internet

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, virtualbox, macbook-pro

I am currently doing a project where a mobile robot needs to be connected to a Linux machine via a local wireless network and the IP address of the computer must not change. I now want to port the setup to a virtual machine running on a Macbook Pro 2015.

I thought about using a USB WiFi dongle to create a second wireless network managed by a software router running on the Linux VM on said Macbook (such that I can assign static IP addresses for the robot and the Linux host). Meanwhile, I want my Macbook's onboard network card to remain connected to my home WiFi.

My question: Will this work? Are there any potential pitfalls that I have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. Just make sure the second USB WiFi dongle is assigned "physically" to the VM.

Also, assign different channels to both WiFis. Make sure they don't overlap (depending on what protocol you use, each "channel number" takes up several channels).